# search substring of base64 encoded string in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, base64

i am trying to find out possible solution to search sub strings from base64 encoded string from MySQL
i am storing title of the product in base64 encoding for example `Ricoh SP 212W` as `Umljb2ggU1AgMjEyVw==`

and now i want to search all products with a possible string "SP" but how i can search "SP" in `Ricoh SP 212W` because this is stored as base64 encoding

this is what i am trying

```
Select * from `prducts` where `product_name` LIKE %SP%
```

but as i already mention `product_name` is stored in Base64 encoding

any suggestion please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Select * from prducts where FROM_BASE64(product_name) LIKE %SP%`

why do you even store product name in base64?

Comment: Overcomplication seems to be a theme today. I have seen it on other questions this morning already. +1 for simplifying the answer.

Comment: FROM_BASE64() is this function came by default

Comment: @ShahrozShary yes, it is built-in MySQL function

Comment: [link](http://prntscr.com/b05h8n) but this is not recognized by mysql . will you please share any working example

Comment: @ShahrozShary it is because argument to LIKE must be quoted '%leather%'

Comment: @ShahrozShary so, what version of MySQL server do you use?